# tex4ebook HTML TIDY, how to install

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

I see on the webpage for `tex4ebook` by @michal.h21,
 https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook @michal.h21

that I can tidy my html code for the output as `.html` and `.epub` from the input of my `.tex`.

I installed `tex4ebook` 40199 version 0.1d from texlive manager.

I installed  `HTML Tidy for Windows version 5.3.9`, from http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?HTML_Tidy_for_HTML5,  and included `tidy.exe` in my `PATH`.
The problem is that `tidy` seems not to find some conf file `tidyconf.conf`. and indeed, I search on disk and there is no file `tidyconf.conf`.
For instance, running `tex4ebook   -l -f epub -t MYTEXFILE.tex`, I get the error `Tidy: Cannot load tidyconf.conf`

```
Execute script `MYTEXFILE.lg'
Make4ht: t4ht  "MYTEXFILE.dvi"
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:28 kpathsea)
t4ht MYTEXFILE.dvi
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
Entering MYTEXFILE.lg
Entering MYTEXFILE.css
Entering MYTEXFILE.tmp
Parse LG
-------------------
Parse LG
Tidy: Cannot load tidyconf.conf
Copy: copy MYTEXFILE.html MYTEXFILE-epub\OEBPS
        1 file copied.
Copy: copy MYTEXFILE.css MYTEXFILE-epub\OEBPS
        1 file copied.
Mimetype for tmp is not registered
Tidy: Cannot load tidyconf.conf
Copy: copy MYTEXFILE2.html MYTEXFILE-epub\OEBPS
        1 file copied.
Tidy: Cannot load tidyconf.conf
Copy: copy MYTEXFILE3.html MYTEXFILE-epub\OEBPS
        1 file copied.
Copy: copy MYTEXFILE.ncx MYTEXFILE-epub\OEBPS
        1 file copied.
Mimetype for opf is not registered
Mimetype for opf is not registered
Copy: copy content.opf MYTEXFILE-epub\OEBPS
        1 file copied.
HTML Tidy for Windows version 5.3.9
Tidy ncx 0
Tidy opf 0
MYTEXFILE-epub/mimetype
Pack mimetype 0
Pack metadir 0
Pack outputdir 0
Copy generated epub
Copy: copy MYTEXFILE-epub\MYTEXFILE.epub MYTEXFILE.epub
        1 file copied.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `tidy` installation is correct, this is a bug in `tex4ebook` distribution, because I omitted this file from the zip file which is posted to CTAN. I should update it, but there were some changes which depends on updated version of `make4ht`, which in turn depends on new features of `LuaXML`, which isn't in the state to be posted to CTAN yet.

meanwhile, you can download [`tidyconf.conf`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/master/tidyconf.conf) from `tex4ebook` repo and put it in the directory with your TeX file, it should work.